# How to embed the binding customization (Schema) directly into the WSDL in JAX-WS using ANT

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, ant, wsdl

I have created the web services using the JAX-WS. My environment consist of the Web Logic, ANT, Spring and Hibernate. Using the build file I compile the web services and deploy it to the app server. I have came across the Dash Board Design which takes the WSDL file as input to produce the desire output. But the issue is that it takes the WSDL file including the Schema into the WSLD. In other words I would like to embed the binding customization directly into the WSDL in JAX-WS using ANT. Is it possible.

Please help